# Creating a template function to read an arbitrary datatype in hdf5

Tags: c++, hdf5

I want to create a template function to read a  dataset with some name in a file. 
These function can read any one of the following types: float, double or long double.
Can I atribute the datatype based on the argument of the template?
right now I only been able of doing it using:

```
template <typename T>
void gethdf(T * l, H5::H5File *  file,  char * name )
{
  H5::DataSet dataset = H5::DataSet(file->openDataSet(name));
  H5::DataType dt;

  if(typeid(T) == typeid(float) )
     dt = H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT;

     ...

 dataset.read(l, dt);
}
```

Comment: Lookup on template specialization / SFINAE. What you have won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what HDF5 is but it looks like you could do the following:

```
template<typename T>
H5::DataType get_datatype_for();

template<>
H5::DataType get_datatype_for<float>() { return H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT; }
```

And then in your function:

```
H5::DataType dt = get_datatype_for<T>();
```

Comment: This is useful! I will implement it! Tks

Answer (score 0):

add extra template which will alter functionality

```
template <typename T>
class DataTypeFor
{
public:
}

template <>
class DataTypeFor<int>
{
public:
    const H5::DataType value = H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT;
}

template <>
class DataTypeFor<float>
{
public:
    const H5::DataType value = H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT;
}

template <>
class DataTypeFor<double>
{
public:
    const H5::DataType value = H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;
}

template <typename T>
void gethdf(T * l, H5::H5File *  file,  char * name )
{
  H5::DataSet dataset = H5::DataSet(file->openDataSet(name));
  H5::DataType dt;

  dt = DataTypeFor<T>::value;
  ...
  dataset.read(l, dt);
}
```